# Basic probability independence in roulette

Tags: probability, independence, gambling

I am teaching my students how roulette works and we were talking about the probability of betting on the first column of numbers $\{1,4,7,10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34\}$ and the probability of betting on 2nd $12$, i.e. $\{13-24\}$.  In my mind these events should be independent.  Thus the probability of landing on the intersection $(13, 16, 19, 22)$ should be
$$
P\big(\{13, 16, 19, 22\}\big)=\frac{12}{38}\cdot\frac{12}{38}, 
$$
but it is clearly $4/38$.  Thus I have a contradiction! What am I missing?

Comment: If we know that we have the first column , zero and double zero are ruled out. This is not the case without this information. In fact, without the zeros we have independent events.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, but I am still slightly baffled by one thing which I will try my best to articulate.  Lets say we weren't playing roulette and instead were calculating numbers from a list, 1-38.  How does looking a the intersection of {1,4,7,10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34} and {13-24} allow me to just "throw out" #37 and #38"?

Comment: They're "almost" independent. If you exclude "0" and "00", or "37" and "38",  they would be. Ie. The probabilities would be 1/3, 1/3 and 1/9.  With "37" and "38" included, the situation changes. 

If you know you're in the first column, it makes it more likely for you to also be in 2nd 12 than knowing nothing at all. Ie. knowing that you're already in first column changes the probability of being in 2nd 12 from 6/38 to 4/12 , If knowing the outcome of one event changes the odds of another event, the two are not independent.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let A be the event of landing on a number in the first column.
Let B be the event of landing on the 12-24.  Then P(A|B)=1/3, but P(A)=12/38. Thus the events in question are not independent.

Comment: What are A and B? Please explain your answer.